# Multilingual Taxonomy Views - Entity Translation

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, entities, i18n-l10n

I am trying to create a multilingual taxonomy view using [Entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation).  So far, I am stuck displaying an English view even when using a language code.

I'm looking for the steps needed for this. At the simplest, I am trying to create blocks or pages of taxonomy terms based on language.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Internationalizations Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module, which extends the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module with multilingual support for views.

Also, to make view results correspond to the language switcher, add a filter for **Content Translation: User's Current Language**, which is the language that an authenticated user has set in the user settings (it is NOT the same as the current browser language or the site language).

If no option for the **User's Current Language** is available in the filter criteria form, then verify your configuration at *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: The order should be **URL, Default, User** and not something like **Default, URL, User** (as mentioned also in https://www.drupal.org/node/1701854#comment-6279474).

The above may turn out to NOT be the complete answer. Since you use the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module, this option isn't there if you use it in 'entity' mode: if only some fields of the node are translatable the option is there but a bit more difficult to find. If you have the 'Body' of your nodes set to translatable entity then the option is "Body language" to be set to Current User Language.

**Note**: The [Internationalizations Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module only has a **DEV** version for D7, but right now there are [over 31K users using this version](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/i18nviews). Therefor I think "DEV" is not a valid release qualifier for that version anymore, because *+31K users can't be wrong*, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you wont to show in views taxonomy terms, translated with entity_translate, try to use
"Entity translation: Name" field 
instead
"Taxonomy term: Name (translated)"